# Can EL value pass one to another in JSF and Facelets?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, ajax4jsf

I would like to pass the EL one JSF page to Facelets template. Facelets template just understand EL value as string value. How can I pass EL String to Faceltes Template?

page1.xthml

```
<ui:include ..../>
<ui:param actionBeanMethod="#{EmployeeActionBean.deleteEmplayee(emp)}>
```

page2.xthml

```
<ui:include ..../>
<ui:param actionBeanMethod="#{DepartmentActionBean.deleteDepartment(dep)}>
```

In comfirmationTemplate.xml

```
    <a4j:commandLink onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.show();return false">
        <h:graphicImage value="/img/delete.png" />
    </a4j:commandLink>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="submit" action="#{actionBeanMethod}"/>                    
    <rich:popupPanel id="confirmation" width="250" height="150">
       <f:facet name="header">Confirmation</f:facet>
       <h:panelGrid>
          <h:panelGrid columns="2">
             <h:graphicImage value="/img/alert.png" />
         <h:outputText value="Are you sure?" style="FONT-SIZE: large;" />
          </h:panelGrid>
          <h:panelGroup>
             <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide();submit();return false" />
         <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('confirmation')}.hide();return false" />
          </h:panelGroup>
       </h:panelGrid>
    </rich:popupPanel>
```

I would like to change action of a4j:jsFuction dynamically.

```
    When page1.xhtm is call,
    <a4j:jsFunction name="submit" action="#{EmployeeActionBean.deleteEmplayee(emp)"/>

    When page2.xhtm is call,
    <a4j:jsFunction name="submit" action="#{DepartmentActionBean.deleteDepartment(dep)"/>
```

Can it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass method expressions as `<ui:param>` value. It accepts only value expressions.

You basically need to create a custom taghandler which re-interprets the value expression as a method expression. From the current open source JSF component/utility libraries, the [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:methodParam>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/methodParam) is the only one which does exactly that.

```
<o:methodParam name="methodParam" value="#{actionBeanMethod}" />
<a4j:jsFunction name="submit" action="#{methodParam}" />
```

You only need to register the Facelets include as a Facelets tag file and use it as

```
<my:confirmationTemplate actionBeanMethod="#{EmployeeActionBean.deleteEmplayee(emp)}" />
```

An alternative is to use a composite component instead.

Comment: thz, for your providing answer. currently, I am using Richfaces. I don't know what will happen if I use together these two

Comment: OmniFaces is not a JSF component library. It is a JSF utility library. So the impact when used together with a JSF component lirbaries is theoretically zero. See also the introductory text in its homepage. For what is worth, we're using it in production together with PrimeFaces 3.x and RichFaces 4.x.

Comment: Although, <o:methodParam> tag is useful to pass the EL String, It doest not work as below; <my:confirmationTemplate actionBeanMethod="#{EmployeeActionBean.deleteEmplayee(emp)}" />It work like; `<my:confirmationTemplate actionBeanMethod="#{EmployeeActionBean.deleteEmplayee}" />` I cannot pass the parameter emp(employee instance value.

Comment: `<o:methodParam>` doesn't know `#{EmployeeActionBean.deleteEmplayee(emp)}`. It just know `#{EmployeeActionBean.deleteEmplayee}`.